# Strange pattern on atand results distribution

Tags: matlab, rounding, histogram, angle

I have tracks of particles, obtained after tracking them on an image sequence (20 particles, 3500 frames). I need to get a distribution of velocities vectors angles of these particles. Positions of the particles on each frame are stored in matrices `tracksX` and `tracksY`, 3500x20 double each. Here is the code I'm using:

```
speedX = diff(tracksX);
speedY = diff(tracksY);
angles = atand(speedY./speedX);
anglesh = angles(:);
figure(1); hist(anglesh,360);
```

However, I am getting a strange symmetrical pattern on the histogram, with a huge peak in a [-0.5, 0] bin and zero angles in [0, 0.5] bin. 
I don't have enough rep to add an image, so here is a link to it [Weird distribution figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3LP5.png)

Could it happen because of some rounding that Matlab performs? How to fix it?
The particles movement is somewhat random with a tendency to move in X direction, corresponding to 0° - 20° bins, so I highly doubt this pattern could appear from the initial data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess: positions are in pixels, and the particles do not move very many pixels between time points?

What you're seeing are a bunch of discretization artifacts.

- Peak at 0 reflecting pixels that are either stationary or move toward the right
- Peaks at +/- 45 and 90 degrees reflecting particles moving one pixel up/down or along the diagonal.
- More peaks for moving e.g. 2 to the right, one to the top

Depending on your data, you might be able to perform some fitting of particle positions to estimate sub-pixel localization (though you should be careful to set it up correctly to avoid pixel-locking), or you could use artificially larger time steps (e.g. take differences between 1st-4th, 2nd-5th, 3rd-6th time points to make the histogram) to make this look a bit more sensible.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it is the case. I thought that distances are long enough, but turned out that indeed there is enough short-distance movements to produce such artifacts.